# Array sorting in below pattern

Tags: php, arrays

I have below array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => workout
            [days] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => restday
            [days] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => df
            [days] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => df
            [days] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => restday
            [days] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => ss
            [days] => 6
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => reday
            [days] => 5
        )

)
```

I want it in this format like the position of array having `ft_name=>"restday"`
should be remain same and the rest are should be sorted in order by `days` field

I have tried with this code but result is not expected.

```
<?php    
$size = count($val);
    for($i=0;$i< $size;$i++){
        if($val[$i]['days']){
            for ($j=0; $j<$size-$i; $j++) {

                if(!$val[$j+1]['days']) continue;   

                if ($val[$j+1]['days'] < $val[$j]['days']) {
                      swap($val, $j, $j+1);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }

    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($val);

    function swap(&$arr, $a, $b) {
        $tmp = $arr[$a];
        $arr[$a] = $arr[$b];
        $arr[$b] = $tmp;
    }
?>
```

Output should be looks like this one

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => df
            [days] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => restday
            [days] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => workout
            [days] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => df
            [days] => 4
        )        

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => restday
            [days] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => reday
            [days] => 5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ft_name] => ss
            [days] => 6
        )

)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a code for free service as you would know, so what have you tried?

Comment: have you tried `array_multisort` ?

Comment: try `array_multisort`

Comment: @Darren I have added the code, please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try `array_multisort` , here you have the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
<?php
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    if ( $row['days'] != '' ){
        $days[$key]  = $row['days'];
        $name[$key] = $row['ft_name']; 
    }else{
        $days[$key] = $key; 
        $name[$key] = $row['ft_name']; 
        }
    }

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($days, SORT_ASC, $name, SORT_ASC, $data);
?>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php) you have a nice post about PHP Sorting arrays

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this code but its changing the position of restday too and I want to keep the position of restday as same.

Comment: you can try adding an if condition inside the foreach, i will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) with a callback function having 2 tests one the main field and if the main field has equal value, test the second field

You can downvote me I misunderstood